# Py-Script commit to a SQL table after submitting an html form

Tags: python, sqlite, pyscript, sqlite3-python

I have a HTML file with a button to submit a form which runs the following Py-Script code:

```
import sqlite3

def sub(*args, **kwargs):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    fname = Element('fname').value.title()
    lname = Element('lname').value.title()
    email = Element('email').value
    pword = Element('pword').value

    sqlite_insert = "INSERT INTO accounts (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
    data_tuple = (fname, lname, email, pword)
    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert, data_tuple)

    conn.commit()
    print("commited")
    conn.close()
    print("closed")
```

I have also added to the py-config tag in the HTML to fetch the correct file: data.sqlite, however even though when the function runs and it prints "commited" and "closed", the new data does not get saved into the SQL database

I would like the new data from the form to be saved to sqlite file once the function sub() is ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch a file to use in Pyscript, presumably with the `[[fetch]]` key in `\<py-config\>`, you are loading the contents of that file into memory in the browser window. Specifically, you are loading it into the [virtual file system](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) that Emscripten instantiates to help C/C++ programs run in Web Assembly. (In this case, the C Program is the CPython interpreter). When you make changes to that file in Python, you are making changes to the in-memory version of that file, not the location where that file was originally loaded from.

To make your changes persistent in the location of the original file, you will need some way of sending either those changes or that file back to its original location. If it's a local file, you can have the user download the database file, or use Chrome's [File System Access API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/) to give the browser direct read/write access to a specific folder. For a database hosted on the web, you're likely looking at making an API request to an endpoint that hosts the database, either directly modifying the database itself or re-uploading the modified database file.